# Hide Empty Field Value and their Labels in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

[image: Like in this image two fields which are empty i just want that if those fields are empty just hide them, and if they contains any value then it shows]

Like in this image two fields which are empty i just want that if those fields are empty just hide them, and if they contains any value then it shows

Here is the Code

```
<?php
                                    $query = mysql_query("select * from clients where clients_id = '$get_id'")or die(mysql_error());
                                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                            ?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Mobile No. ( ਮੋਬਿਲੇ ਨੋ.  ) - </b> <?php echo $row['mobile']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>

<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Landline - </b> <?php echo $row['landline']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Add. Address - </b> <?php echo $row['addaddress']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Add. VPO/City - </b> <?php echo $row['addcity']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check if they are `empty` or not -

```
$val = trim($row['addaddress']);
if(!empty($val)) {
     // display the table row or column
}
```

For you code it should be something like -

```
$val = trim($row['addaddress']);
if(!empty($val)) {
?>
    <td>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
    normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
    "Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Add. Address - </b> <?php echo $row['addaddress']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p> </p>
    </td>
<?php
}
```

[Read this before using empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Use the check depending on the values. With `empty()`, if the value is `0` it will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for Providing me correct path to the Problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition to check if value is empty or not. It will not echo the html it it's empty.

```
<?php if(!empty($row['addcity'])): ?>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><b>Add. VPO/City - </b> <?php echo $row['addcity']; ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for Providing me correct path to the Problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Need to chek the not empty condition:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><?php if(!empty($row['mobile'])){ echo "<b>Mobile No. ( ਮੋਬਿਲੇ ਨੋ.  ) - </b> ".$row['mobile']."" } ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>

<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><?php if(!empty($row['landline'])){ echo"<b>Landline - </b> ".$row['landline']."" } ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><?php if(!empty($row['addaddress'])){ echo"<b>Add. Address - </b> ".$row['addaddress']."" } ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
<td>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'><?php if(!empty($row['addcity'])){ echo "<b>Add. VPO/City - </b> ".$row['addcity']."" ?><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p> </p>
</td>

</table>
```